# rename the arraylist value coverting json to normal object?

Tags: java, json, arraylist

```
public class Student {

  String name = "jai";
  int rollno = 111;
  String address = "chennai";

  public static void main(String[] agrs) {
    Student st = new Student();
    //System.out.println(st.name);
    //System.out.println(st.rollno);
    //System.out.println(st.address);
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

    al.add(st);

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    String str = gson.toJson(al);

    System.out.println(str);

    ArrayList a2 = new ArrayList();

    a2.add(str);

    a2.add("us");

    System.out.println(a2);

    ArrayList a3 = gson.fromJson(str, ArrayList.class);

    System.out.println(a3);

    ArrayList a4 = gson.fromJson(str, ArrayList.class);

    a4.set(0, "ram");
     System.out.println(a4);

  }
}
```

> error:com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was
>   BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2

Comment: output:[{"name":"jai","rollno":111,"address":"chennai"}]
[[{"name":"jai","rollno":111,"address":"chennai"}],us]
[{name=jai, rollno=111.0, address=chennai}].but i need [{name=ram, rollno=111.0, address=chennai}].

Comment: something went wrong because {"name":"jai","rollno":111,"address":"chennai"} here rollno/name is not available into class as you had shown above then how comes into json

Comment: 2. why {"name":"jai","rollno":111,"address":"chennai"} again and again comes into JSon String , as per code only 1-student object inside list not more. ca you please make me correct so that i can understand it more clearly

Comment: how to change name? first array a1  i got name=jai, second a2=jai,third a3=jai,but i need a4 arraylist value name=ram..

Comment: here problem i am phasing is ArrayList[non-generic], can we by pass ArrayList ? i mean we can directly work with Student ?